# Import Database to MySQL via WAMP server

Tags: mysql, sql, wamp

I use SQL Server Management Studio to manage a database I've created, 'COMPANY', and am now attempting to write some PHP code to query the database.

However, I first need to have the database in MySQL before I can attempt to connect to it. I've downloaded WAMP server and have a `.sql` file containing a script for re-creating my database.

I'm unable to import my database into MySQL, though. I've tried

```
mysql> source /pathname/company.sql
```

But every time I execute the command, something flashes in the MySQL console window and then the window closes. Other times I get `Error 22: File not found`

How can I successfully execute my SQL file?

Comment: That's a UNIX style filepath. I wouldn't expect that to work on Windows.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3217453/convert-sql-server-database-to-mysql

Comment: please consider showing some lines from your .sql file.

Comment: You cannot load a SQLServer dump to a MySQL server, but here is a post that should give you lots of options for finding a migration tool. http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3153/need-to-migrate-sql-server-to-mysql

Comment: Thank you! I just ended up running the same CREATE statements in MySQL, and that seemed to work just fine. Tedious, but it worked :P

Comment: Actually thinking about it, you can access a SQLServer database from PHP. Why bother to convert it to MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

First create the db and
Try

> mysql -u root -p dbName< '/pathname/company.sql'